# Remove words containg asterisks or dots

Tags: javascript, regex, contains, words

I'm looking for a way to remove words or numbers containing these characters: `*` or `.`.

I tried to write my own regex but i couldn't really figure it out. For example

> The sh*t just hit the fan 102.7 and google.com

Should result in:

> The just hit the fan and

Just a random sentence but it should remove the words `sh*t`, `102.7` and `google.com`.

It doesn't matter if it'll leave double spaces.

Thanks in advance and I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
result = subject.replace(/\S*[.*]\S*/g, "");
```

should do it.

**Explanation:**

```
\S*  # match any number of non-whitespace characters
[.*] # match either a dot or an asterisk
\S*  # match any number of non-whitespace characters
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! Works like a charm!

Comment: +1 note that this leaves two spaces where a word has been removed.

Comment: If there's a `.` or `*` at the beginning or end of a string, and that character is directly adjacent to a word, the character and the word will be removed. The period at the end of a sentence will cause the last word in the sentence to be removed.

Comment: Thnx for the extra replies and the explanation. I now realise what I was doing wrong. My strings won't contain dots at the end of sentences and the double spaces also won't matter to me. Even though all that, I appreciate it!

Comment: @FailedDev Sorry, first time here!